# Is there an efficient way in Java to search for multiple words (not next to each other) in the same String value?

Tags: java, database, roles, contains, identity

We pull a lot of our data from an authoritative source into various attributes in our environment.

One of those attributes we have is "jobTitle" - as the name suggests, it's an identity's respective job title at the organization.

One of my primary jobs is to create Assignment Rules for Roles at the organization and I've run into an issue that I believe can be done more efficiently, but am missing the java knowledge

So here's the problem:

We use the following Java line to "get" any specific jobTitle in our org that has Nurse in it: `identity.getAttribute("jobTitle").contains("Nurse");`

My question for you Java experts - is there a way I utilize wildcards where I can pull all job titles that contain %Nursing%Specialist% or %Nursing%Coordinator% ..

So if I wanted to **provision** the role to all users who have a **jobTitle** of "Nursing Professional Development Specialist" or "Nursing Resource Coordinator" for example where the words *Coordinator* and *Specialist* could possibly be separated by other strings.

Is there an efficient way in Java to overcome this challenge?

For example-

Currently are returning true if the following match:

```
return "Nursing Care Coordinator".equalsIgnoreCase(identity.getAttribute("jobTitle")) || "Nursing Resource Coordinator".equalsIgnoreCase(identity.getAttribute("jobTitle")) || "Nursing Practice Specialist".equalsIgnoreCase(identity.getAttribute("jobTitle")) ||  "Nursing Professional Development Specialist".equalsIgnoreCase(identity.getAttribute("jobTitle"));
```

%Nursing%Specialist% - those % could be other strings such as Professional Nursing Development Specialist , so just trying to make sure all necessary job titles get the correct roles. Would like to not have to be able to type out every specific job title!!

Comment: Efficient in which sense, where's the data stored (eg use native functionality if you can), how much data is there, do you need robust stemming or are regex enough, etc? "Efficient" can mean several things.

Comment: @DaveNewton  Sorry I meant it more in the sense where it accomplishes the ultimate goal of being able to sift through the database and find the correct Job Title Strings.

Comment: Then it depends on the database *(and desired accuracy)*. Most DBs have a form of regex-y text search; how efficient it is *(or can be)* varies. The implementation depends on where/how you want to do the work.

Comment: I'm essentially just trying to optimize by not having to type out the specific job title for each and every query. The statement returns true and will assign the role if all of the checks come back at true. I edited my post to provide an example snippet of how we've currently been going about it.

Comment: The problem is the corpus of "the same" job titles may or may not be dynamic. Those rules **may** be capturable by regex (or a series of them), **may** be better with a combination of stemming rules and other means *(including regex)*, or may be buildable with the existing data and a simple tool that clumps them together. Hard to say.

Comment: Do you mean that your search is "Nursing" is required, and "Specialist" or "Coordinator" are optional? Your Question is vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it efficiently for the programmer (one expression) using regex. To match "Nurse" or "Nursing .... Specialist" or "Nursing .... Coordinator":

```
identity.getAttribute("jobTitle")
  .matches("^(?=Nurse$|Nursing.*(Coordinator|Specialist)$).*")
```

and it's reasonably efficient for the machine.

See [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/sft3io/1) for a full explanation of the regex.

---

If you just wanted to assert that the terms appear in any order, you would use two look aheads - one for each term:

```
matches("^(?=.*Nurs(e|ing))(?=.*(Coordinator|Specialist)).*")
```

Comment: So I'm testing identity.getAttribute("jobTitle").matches("^(?=.*Nursing.*(Coordinator)).*"

on a user who has a jobTitle = "Nursing Care Coordinator"


Would this mean that "Nursing" exists and then after the string Nursing, the word Coordinator exists? So it should apply to this user?

Comment: You're trying the "in any order" approach - option 2 in my answer. To require in-order match, use option 1, eg `"^(?=.*Nursing.*Coordinator).*"`. I've edited my answer somewhat - have another read.

Comment: That makes sense! I'm glad I posted today, had no idea about regex. I have "Nurse" taken care of using .contains -- to put it all together could I do the following (simply because we have a few Nursing Students and Nursing Assistants that should not get the role:  
-------
identity.getAttribute("jobTitle").contains("Nurse")
   || identity.getAttribute("jobTitle").matches("^(?=.*Nursing).*(Coordinator|Specialist)).*")

Comment: The way I understand the above is it should provision to all users with a Job Title of "Nurse" or "Nursing .... Specialist" or "Nursing .... Coordinator"

Comment: @Cole Ah. I have updated my answer to the specification in your comment, ie `.matches("^(?=Nurse$|Nursing.*(Coordinator|Specialist)$).*")` will match exactly *"Nurse" or "Nursing .... Specialist" or "Nursing .... Coordinator"*

Comment: I had one more question - what if we had a jobTitle of "Lead Nurse" or "Staff Nurse" - so essentially I want the user to get the role if they have any mention of %Nurse% in their job title. But the only ones with Nursing should be  %Nursing%Coordinator% or %Nursing%Specialist%

Where the "%" denotes Strings that could be before or after at that place.

Comment: @Cole then you would use `matches("^(?=.*Nurse|.*Nursing.*(Coordinator|Specialist)).*")`

Answer (score 2):

As @Dave Newton points out, the term "efficient" is open pretty broadly to interpretation.

One approach would be simply to do a count of how many "keywords" are in a given jobTitle, return that count and action off it.  Something like:

```java
public static boolean containsMultipleKeywords(String jobTitle) {
  // for case-insensitive comparison
  jobTitle = jobTitle.toLowerCase();

  // Set of keywords to check
  Set<String> keywords = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("nurse", "coordinator", "director"));

  // Count the occurrences of keywords
  int count = 0;
  for (String keyword : keywords) {
    if (jobTitle.contains(keyword)) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  // Return true if at least two keywords are found
  return count >= 2;
}
```

Alternatively you could use a regular expression:

```java
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(nurse|coordinator|director)\\b");

  // Matcher to find matches in the jobTitle
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(jobTitle);

  // Count the number of matches
  int count = 0;
  while (matcher.find()) {
    count++;
  }
```

Comment: A couple of suggestions.  Pass the minimum threshold count as an argument.  Put `(?i)` at the beginning of your regex to ignore case. And you can count the matches as follows. `pattern.matcher(title).results().count())` which counts the match results.  But your way is probably more efficient just using a loop.

Comment: @BIBOOunit1998X My example was directive, not prescriptive.  There are a bunch of things I'd like do to the algorithm (word weighting, fuzzy matches, etc.) 

Answer (score 1):

Searching for multiple words not necessarily adjacent in a string can be handled using regular expressions.

You can use Java's 'Pattern' and 'Matcher' classes from java.util.regex to accomplish this.  You can use [regexr](https://regexr.com) to help you build and test your regular expression.

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class MultiWordSearch {
    public static boolean containsWords(String input, String[] words) {
        // Building a regex pattern like "(?=.*word1)(?=.*word2)(?=.*word3).*"
        StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder();
        for (String word : words) {
            regex.append("(?=.*").append(Pattern.quote(word)).append(")");
        }
        regex.append(".*");

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex.toString(), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

        return matcher.matches();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "This is a sample string to search";
        String[] words = {"sample", "search"};

        System.out.println("Contains words: " + containsWords(input, words));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build a predicate to check for complete matches. Then apply it to the title. The more parameters, the fewer likely hits.

```
String[] titles = {"obstetrics nurse admin","Nurse Admin obstetrics",
        "obstetrics admin nurse","obstetrics nurse"};

String[] traits = {"nurse","admin","obstetrics"};

Predicate<String> check = buildPredicate(traits);
for (String title :titles) {
    System.out.println(title + " -> " + check.test(title.toLowerCase()));
}
    

static Predicate<String> buildPredicate(String[] info) {
     Predicate<String> pred = s -> s.contains(info[0]);
     for (int i = 1; i < info.length; i++) {
         final int k = i;
         pred = pred.and(s -> s.contains(info[k]));
     }
     return pred;
}
```

prints

```
obstetrics nurse admin -> true
Nurse Admin obstetrics -> true
obstetrics admin nurse -> true
obstetrics nurse -> false
```

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

Filter a list of strings, looking for those that (a) contain the word *Nursing*, AND (b) contain either the word *Specialist* or the word *Coordinator*.

```java
Stream.of (
                "Nursing Professional Development Specialist" ,  // Hit
                "Accountant" ,  // Miss
                "Nursing Manager" ,  // Miss
                "Nursing Resource Coordinator"  // Hit
        )
        .filter (
                ( String job ) ->
                        Arrays.stream ( job.split ( " " ) ).anyMatch ( Set.of ( "Nursing" ) :: contains )
                        &&
                        Arrays.stream ( job.split ( " " ) ).anyMatch ( Set.of ( "Specialist" , "Coordinator" ) :: contains )
        )
        .toList ( );
```

> [Nursing Professional Development Specialist, Nursing Resource Coordinator]

### Filtering streams

You can make a `Stream` of the words in each job title. Calling `String#split` produces an array. Pass the array to `Arrays.stream` to produce a stream of strings, a stream of the words in the job title.

```
Arrays.stream ( job.split ( " " ) )
```

Some sample data:

```java
Collection < String > jobs =
        List.of (
                "Nursing Professional Development Specialist" ,  // Hit
                "Accountant" ,  // Miss
                "Nursing Manager" ,  // Miss
                "Nursing Resource Coordinator"  // Hit
        );
```

Define our targets.

```java
Set < String > x = Set.of ( "Nursing" );
Set < String > y = Set.of ( "Specialist" , "Coordinator" );
```

Apply each of those sets of targets as a predicate of a filter on the stream of job titles. Collect the job titles that pass our test.

```java
Collection < String > hits =
        jobs
                .stream ( )
                .filter (
                        ( String job ) ->
                                Arrays.stream ( job.split ( " " ) ).anyMatch ( x :: contains )
                )
                .filter (
                        ( String job ) ->
                                Arrays.stream ( job.split ( " " ) ).anyMatch ( y :: contains )
                )
                .toList ( );
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println ( "hits = " + hits );
```

> hits = [Nursing Professional Development Specialist, Nursing Resource Coordinator]

---

We could combine our predicate tests. But I might prefer the original longer version using separate `filter` calls.

```java
Collection < String > hits =
        jobs
                .stream ( )
                .filter (
                        ( String job ) ->
                                Arrays.stream ( job.split ( " " ) ).anyMatch ( x :: contains )
                                        &&
                                        Arrays.stream ( job.split ( " " ) ).anyMatch ( y :: contains )
                )
                .toList ( );
```